# CSS List with column padding

Tags: css, list

I have created an unordered list with three columns. The columns touch when going responsive and shrinking the resolution. What can I use to give somesort of padding between them?

```
.li-3col {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
     column-count: 3;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the column-gap property:

```
.li-3col {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
     column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;
 }
```

You can learn more about the column-gap property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-gap.asp).